# "windows cannot access the specified device....." error in c++

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, exe

I am MFC guy working on visual studio 2010 create some executables using visual studio!! but on linux and mac my executables are not working as usual windows!!.
So i decided to use **"MinGW"** compiler to create executables.

**Note:-Please give me one suggestion is that," is minGW is best compiler for cross plateform working ??or any thing else is there??"**

I successfully install WinGW compiler on my C drive and start working with following program..

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
  cout << "Hello ";
  return 0;
}
```

I compile it using following command,

**g++ -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ Main.cpp**

I found one executable in same folder with name a.exe :).Working fine:)

But after some time i decide to modified same program in following manner like,

```
int main ()
{
  return 0;
}
```

I compile it with same command but when i execute it using command line it show me error **"Access is denied** so i goto that folder and run same executable as **"Run as Administrator"** it show me one messagebox with the message **windows cannot access the specified device path or file. you may not have appropriate permissions**

**---EDIT--**

follwing code is NOT WORKING:-

```
 int main ()
 {
      int k;
      return 0;
  }
```

but this program WORKING :-

```
int main()
{
  int k;
  k = 0;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just to prepare you: Microsoft had a habit of keeping things like AFX and various other MFC-related headers proprietary. That means a lot of C++ programming examples provided by Microsoft simply will *never* compile on MinGW. But the standard Windows C API should be well supported.

Comment: @PP. i known my programs has lots of "AFX" things from message box to AfxLoadLibrary() but we found some alternative for same!!

Comment: Try to re-run at a later time.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY not working!!I keep my computer off last 2 days but same error observe!!

Comment: Would you working in the system folder?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY No i am working on desktop!!

Comment: It looks like you need at least one statement (not declaration) before the return value.  Can you test with another dummy statement, e.g. int k; k = k; return(0) ?

Comment: Can you try compiling it with something on the mac or linux computer and see if it works like that?  Although I'm guessing maybe it's a difference in the way visual studio and minGW handle variables that are initialized but not defined... I know next to nothing about c++ and visual studio, and absolutely nothing about minGW, but in a javascript project I am working on I was having a variable not defined error when I created a variable but didn't assign a value to it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting this access denied error, then the most likely cause is that the executable file is open in another process, probably the linker or debugger. Try installing [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and hit `Ctrl+F` and type in the name of your .exe. This should show the processes that the .exe file open. Kill those processes (or if you are still debugging, then end debugging first). You then should be able to build again.

Note that this has nothing to do with Microsoft APIs, as in any case you're using gcc.

EDIT: If there are no processes holding the .exe then it may be that there is some other kind of permission problem. Does the .exe file exist?  Can you delete the file and rebuild?  Another thing to try is run Process Monitor and filter for the name of the .exe -- that may show a regular permission denied error, or perhaps another error such as a sharing conflict.

Answer (score 1):

> Note:-Please give me one suggestion is that," is minGW is best compiler for cross plateform working ??or any thing else is there??"

No. And there's nothing else out there.

Use whatever compiler is available on target platform, ensure your code compiles on all of them.
Avoid platform-specific and compiler-specific code at all costs (use cross-platform frameworks).

> I successfully install WinGW

There are many different versions of mingw provided by different sites. If you install compiler from mingw.org using mingw-get, it'll probably work. If you install mingw from some other site, it may or may not work.

> I compile it using following command,

Use a build systems. cmake, qmake or something similar.

> it show me error "Access is denied

Launch **[process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)** and see after which system call it terminates. It is also possible that your antivirus software interferes with your program, or maybe there's some stray dll in your path or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions for the entire folder in which the executable resides.  Trying to 'Run as Administrator' doesn't have any effect if the folder doesn't allow the permissions.

Comment: yups i alredy do this!!! my "#include <iostream> using namespace std;...." working fine but normal program with only main method is not working!!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have anything to do with your code.  This is an environmental problem, something is pretty messed up about the permissions your user account has for one or more of the directories on your hard disk.  The generic diagnostic is that the default working directory for the program does not permit read or list access.

A possible starting point would be to use Explorer and right-click the directory where MinGW is installed.  Use the Security tab and ensure that your user account has all permissions enabled.  Further narrow it down to trying to run the program from the command prompt, using different directories as the default directory.